# How to add a UIbutton in a TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I tried adding a `UIButton` to a `TableViewCell`, but I realized that I can't add an outlet because my cell is repeating.

How can I access the `UIButton` as a `IBOutlet` in my `.m` file?

Comment: you can use tag instead of outlet or use separate class file for cell to make an outlet from tableview

Comment: @farhan ur subclassing the cell or not?

Comment: what the problem u faced ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview deque....];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [cell.contentView addsubview:btn];
}
```

add this in **CellForRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: We set the tag for the button to take them again. I think you should  set the  tag for the button is constant.  `btn.tag = MY_BUTTON_TAG`.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a class extenson in TableViewCell.m file above 
@implementation ScheduleDateCell like below

```
@interface TableViewCell ()
{

}
@end
```

Then  in your xib you can add a button and right-click drag your button to the .m file in Assistant Editor mode

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate class for UITableViewCell and then can create outlet of button and then you can access button from custom cell class object. For example, create object of UITableViewCell custom class:

```
KBTableViewCell *cell;   //here KBTableViewCell is custom class for UITableViewCell
```

and then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
cell.btnMore.tag = indexPath.row; //here btnMore is my button, here do whatever you want to
```